# Fluent Nhibernate : How to make Search Class Generic in best possible way

Tags: c#, fluent-nhibernate

I have a class say 'AllInvoices', the structure of which is as below :

```
public class ActiveInvoices
{
    public string InvoiceId { get; set; }
    public string InvoiceIssueDate { get; set; }
    public string InvoiceTransactionDate { get; set; }
    public string InvoiceExpiryDate { get; set; }
}
```

The mapping class for Entity ActiveInvoices is

```
public class ActiveInvoicesMap : ClassMap<ActiveInvoices>
{
    public ActiveInvoicesMap()
    {
        Id(x => x.InvoiceId);
        Map(x => x.InvoiceIssueDate);
        Map(x => x.InvoiceTransactionDate);
        Map(x => x.InvoiceExpiryDate);
    }
}
```

Now with this entity I search for Active Invoices in database with the following class

```
public class SearchInvoices
{
    public readonly IRepository<ActiveInvoices> latestActiveInvoicesRepository;

    public SearchInvoices(IRepository<ActiveInvoices> activeInvoicesRepository)
    {
        latestActiveInvoicesRepository = activeInvoicesRepository;
    }

    public List<ActiveInvoices> GetActiveInvoices()
    {
        var listOfActiveInvoices = latestActiveInvoicesRepository.GetAll();
        return listOfActiveInvoices;
    }
}
```

To Search Active Invoices I call the Search Class method 'GetActiveInvoices()' from a workflow class which looks like below :

```
public class CurrentWorkFlow
{
    public void GetActiveInvoices()
    {
        var invoiceSearch = new SearchInvoices(IRepository <ActiveInvoices> repository);
    }
}
```

Now the issue in hand is that I need to make class 'SearchInvoices' generic to support all other possible types that i would create like 'ExpiredInvoices', 'ArchivedInvoices', 'FutureInvoices' etc and not just only for type 'ActiveInvoices'.
These new types may or may not have the same structure as 'ActiveInvoices'.
I have tried to use dynamic but thought of asking experts around here if they have any better ideas to implement the required functionality 
in most optimized generic manner.

Regrets for being very detailed and lengthy in asking but i thought to include as many details as i can. Hope it goes well with you folks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Couldn't you make a generic repository like this? -

```
interface IDomain{
}

class ExpiredInvoices: IDomain{
}

class ActiveInvoices: IDomain{
}

interface IRepository{
}

class Repsoitory: IRepository  {
      public static IList<T> Get<T>() where T: IDomain //default one
      {
          using (ISession session = OpenEngineSession())
          {
              return session.Query<T>().ToList();
          }
      }
      public static IList<T> Get<T>(Expression<Func<T, bool>> expression) where T: IDomain // overloaded get with linq predicate
      {
          using (ISession session = OpenEngineSession())
          {
              return session.Query<T>().Where(expression).ToList();
          }
      }
}
```

Then use it like -

```
var repo = // get  IRepository

var activeInvoices = repo.Get<ActiveInvoices>();
var expiredInvoices = repo.Get<ExpiredInvoices>();
```

**EDIT: As Repository cannot be changed, suggested by OP**

If you cannot change the repository, then I would suggest making the search service `interface` dependent, rather than `concrete` class -

```
interface IInvoice{
}

class ExpiredInvoices: IInvoice{
}

class ActiveInvoices: IInvoice{
}


public class SearchInvoices
{
    public readonly IRepository<IInvoice> latestActiveInvoicesRepository;

    public SearchInvoices(IRepository<IInvoice> activeInvoicesRepository)
    {
        latestInvoicesRepository = activeInvoicesRepository;
    }

    public List<T> GetActiveInvoices<T>() where T: IInvoice
    {
        var listOfActiveInvoices = latestActiveInvoicesRepository.GetAll();
        return listOfActiveInvoices;
    }
}
```

Then call like -

```
var ss = new SearchService(IRepository <ActiveInvoices> repository);
var items = ss.GetActiveInvoices<ActiveInvoices>();
```

Or,

```
public class SearchInvoices<T> where T: IInvoice
{
    public readonly IRepository<T> latestActiveInvoicesRepository;

    public SearchInvoices(IRepository<T> activeInvoicesRepository)
    {
        latestInvoicesRepository = activeInvoicesRepository;
    }

    public List<T> GetActiveInvoices() 
    {
        var listOfActiveInvoices = latestActiveInvoicesRepository.GetAll();
        return listOfActiveInvoices;
    }
}
```

then call like -

```
var ss = new SearchService<ActiveInvoices>(IRepository <ActiveInvoices> repository);
var items = ss.GetActiveInvoices();
```

Whichever suits you.

Comment: Thanks for the answer mate!! but creation of repository is through a wrapper dll which again is organization wide and changing that is unfortunately not possible!!!

However I was thinking to make the method "GetActiveInvoices()" generic. what's say ?

Comment: Wow!!! That sounds great mate!!! i would certainly give this one a +1. 
Just one more point, If I understood correctly in the edited solution the interface 'IInvoice' will have all the properties from classes like 'ActiveInvoices', 'ExpiredInvoices' and these classes will implement interface IInvoice ? And these classes will only have either no properties or at the least different properties. ?

Comment: They can have different properties, the point is only to make them implement one interface, so that they can be used as a generic parameter. So it does not matter which properties they have.